# Can I get my comment's reactions in FB Graph API Explorer

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I wrote a comment to a post on a FB page. Is it possible to get its reactions (type and user name) with Graph API Explorer?
I assigned likes permission to the user token. Now the GET looks:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/<comment id>/likes
```

also tried:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/<comment id>?fields=likes
```

Both returns with:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) Missing Permissions",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "fbtrace_id": "<id>"
  }
}
```